# JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) - DELPHI Rest Datasnap

Tags: django, rest, delphi, datasnap

I'm trying to make a POST request in the delphi language, as a client and Django as a server. But when doing the POST is giving the error:

> {
> "detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
> }

All the authentication part is working correctly, I can make GET requests without problems.

Source code used in PostMan cURL

```
curl --location --request POST 'myUrl/api/v1/grupos/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"id":9,"grupo":"TESTE","id_empresa":26,"prioridade":0}'
```

Source code used to add my json to the body of the request.

```
    sJson := '{"id":9,"grupo":"TESTE","id_empresa":26,"prioridade":0}';
    RESTRequest.Body.ClearBody;

    with RESTRequest.Params.AddItem do
      begin
        name := 'body';
        Value := sJson;
        Kind := pkREQUESTBODY;
        ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
      end;

    RESTRequest.Execute;

    Result.Value := RESTResponse.content;
    Result.StatusCode := RESTResponse.StatusCode;
    Result.Mensagem := RESTResponse.StatusText;
```

Making the same request through PostMan everything goes well, but not when I do it through my application.

Would anyone know the resolution of this ??

Comment: Could you add the cURL code snippet from Postman to clarify your request please?

Comment: Why would you provide `{"` and the error message comes up with `{ "` - did you notice the space in there appearing for no reason? Let alone that I nowhere see you ever provided `"detail"` as name.

Comment: @Xalo added the Postman cUrl!

Answer (score 1):

To add data to the body of your request, use

```
RESTRequest.AddBody(sJson, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```